# Is $x=\infty$ a solution to $|x+1|=|x+2|$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Solve : $|x+1|=|x+2|$

One solution is: $x=-\frac{3}{2}$

But is : $x=\infty$ accepted/considered a solution to such an equation?

Comment: Probably not, if not specifically told to allow for the extended real line.

Comment: A chain of questions must be answered in this regard : Is infinity a number of a symbol? Can addition be extended to infinity? Can $- \infty$ be well defined? Can the modulus function be extended to infinity? Then only can you think of answering this question. I am not trying to scare you, but approaching questions regarding infinity is not easy in all contexts, specially this one. Depending upon your definition of $\infty$, the modulus function at the point, and additions of functions with infinity, the answer may or may not be right. My hunch is, this is not accepted as a solution.

Comment: Short answer: no.

Long answer: nnnnnnnnnnnnnnooooooooooooooooooooooo.

Comment: Short answer: sometimes, depending on previous assumptions as touched on above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$|x+1|=|x+2|$ by itself is technically not a full expression. You need to specify what set is being considered for $x$. For example, if $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ it has no solutions. If $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ it has one solution ($-3/2$). Generally we use context to infer what the correct domain for the variable is, but the "default" assumption tends to be $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{Q}$. When the domain is something else (be it $\mathbb R\cup\{\infty\}$ or $\mathbb F_p$ or **Card**) we tend to expect that to be specified.

So yes, there are mathematical objects where there are infinite "numbers" that satisfy that equation, such as the surreal numbers or the class of cardinals. However, no one is going to look at that equation and assume that's what you mean.

Comment: But note that for ordinals, the vertical bars are interpreted as cardinality, and not as absolute value. So the solutions in the ordinals really solve a different equation.

Comment: @martin.koeberl That's true, but I feel like it only furthers my point about the importance of context. Besides, given the right construction of $\mathbb{Z}$ it denotes cardinality on $\mathbb{Z}$ in a way that can be generalized to $\mathbb R$!

Comment: Well, certainly, but I'm not sure whether every person reading here is aware of that. Also, I don't think OP was intending the cardinality-interpretation. If you just define absolute value for ordinals in the obvious way it doesn't have any solutions in the ordinals. (I don't have any intention in invalidating your answer; just a few comments.)

Comment: @martin.koeberl Isn't the obvious definition for ordinals to make it the identity function?

Comment: Yes, of course (so quite unnecessary obviously).

Comment: @martin.koeberl Ah right. no solution in the ordinals, but solutions in the cardinals!